# swc cannot show public members in flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create an as3 library (.swc), but weird thing happened. In flash builder 4.7, I can only see the classes of the swc just created, but cannot see the public members. The swc is totally ok to be used, but it doesn't show the public members in package explorer in flash builder 4.7. Does any one know how to fix? Thanks.